# Use of undefined constant CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX - assumed 'CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX'

Tags: laravel, push-notification

I am using [pushok](https://github.com/edamov/pushok) library to send push notification. While i am using the function it throws me

[image: CURLLPIPE_MULTIPLEX]

The requirement of this package is

```
PHP >= 7.0
lib-curl >= 7.46.0 (with http/2 support enabled)
lib-openssl >= 1.0.2e
```

my ubuntu linux server meets the all above requirements, here is detail [issue](https://github.com/edamov/pushok/issues/9) report on git

Comment: That doesn't seem to be same error as the github link you offered.  I think this is probably closer https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74050.  Have you installed `php7.0-curl`?

Comment: Yes i have install php7.0-curl, it seems my CURL HTTP2 is not enabled

Comment: I have enabled HTTP2 as well but still same issue